# IOS App developed using Xcode 4.6 can be comptaible with recent Iphone versions

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, osx-lion

I have owned a MacBook (13 Inch) with OSX 10.7 (Lion version), and I found that the latest Xcode version comptabile with this computer is 4.6, which allow to create applications using IOS6 SDK.

Can I develop applications using IOS6 SDK and same time be able to run them on latest Apple Iphone devices and publish those apps on AppStore?

Comment: Mohammed make sure that my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Testing Legacy Tool Support Says](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1806/_index.html)

> For compatibility reasons, the App Store will often accept apps that
>   are built with some older versions of Xcode or Base SDK.
>
> To determine if an older Xcode configuration is currently accepted by
>   the App Store, you can choose "Archive" under the "Product" menu to
>   make an archived build, then use the Validate feature, to test if that
>   build meets minimum requirements for submission to the App Store.
>
> You may find it easier to create a test test bundle ID in the Member
>   Center and application record in iTunes Connect to test your build
>   environment, so you don't need to correctly configure every
>   entitlement your app uses.

Before 1 year when I submitted the app to app store I found out that

> If I had lowest version I could not upload app to app store.Then I downloaded
>   xCode 6 also I must have minimum iOS 7.So you
>   should have **minimum xCode version 6**.Unless you have xCode 6, you must
>   not submit he app to app store.
>
> At the same time you should have **minimum iOS version  or deployment target 7**

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is yes. The big requirement is that your apps be 64 bit. The app store no longer supports 32 bit apps.

If you build apps on an older version of Xcode you won't be able to install/debug those apps from Xcode onto devices running newer OS versions, but you should be able to build an IPA and install it through iTunes.